# How to remove a SwiftyJSON element?

Tags: ios, swift, swifty-json

I have a JSON array (say, `dataObj`) generated by [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON) and I try to remove its element like this:

```
let count=dataObj.count
for var m=x; m<count; ++m {
    dataObj[m] = nil  // there is no removeAtIndex() somehow
}

print(dataObj.count)
print(dataObj)
```

After execution, `dataObj.count` remains the same and `print` shows now `dataObj` becomes

[null,
null,
null,
...
]

What's the way to really remove an element for SwiftyJSON?

Comment: dataObj.removeAtIndex[m] or dataObj.removeAll() ... etc.

Comment: Removing an object in a repeat loop by (increasing) index is a very bad idea. Assuming you have two elements and you have just removed `object[0]`. Then `object[1]` becomes `object[0`] and there is no index `1` anymore. That causes a pretty `out of bounds` exception. The only (safe) way to remove by index in a repeat loop is removing backwards.

Comment: @vadian Thanks I will remove backwards.

Comment: @user3441734 If I can use that directly, I will not ask this question.

Comment: why you can't?  by the way, if you want to remove all elements, why not to use removeAll() ?? as sad by vadian: "The only (safe) way to remove by index in a repeat loop is removing backwards" is true if you will remove the last element only. in that case you can use while dataObj.count > 0 { dataObj.removeLast() } or (without using index) while dataObj.count > 0 { dataObj.removeFirst() }.

Comment: ... (continue) so, simple use removeAll(). if you have some other criteria for remove / not remove inside the loop, use filter instead.

Comment: @user3441732 there is no such method for the returned JSON type by SwiftyJSON. Although it's like an array but it has no such a method.

Comment: @EricD. Thanks but I found the answer. I thought about making Swift objects but in that case, I rather give up using SwiftyJSON. I don't want to do the extra copying if the library does not allow me to alter data while I am trying to do extra parsing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Finally I found the answer to remove an element in JSON (array type) created by SwiftyJSON:

```
dataObj.arrayObject?.removeAtIndex(m)
```

By the way, to remove an element when JSON returned by SwiftyJSON in a dictionary type:

```
jsonObj.dictionaryObject?.removeValueForKey(keyValue)
```

**Update**

Swift 3+ -

Array:

```
dataObj.arrayObject?.remove(at: m)
```

Dictionary:

```
jsonObj.dictionaryObject?.removeValue(forKey: keyValue)
```

Answer (score 5):

Update on Joe's answer for Swift 4.

Removing a `dictionary` element from JSON:

```
json.dictionaryObject?.removeValue(forKey: key)
```

Removing an `array` element from JSON:

```
json.arrayObject?.remove(at: index)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are storing dictionaries, you can remove elements using `dictionaryObject.removeValue(forKey:)`. This mutates the JSON object in place.

For example:

```swift
var object = JSON([
    "one": ["color": "blue"],
    "two": ["city": "tokyo",
            "country": "japan",
            "foods": [
                "breakfast": "tea",
                "lunch": "sushi"
                ]
            ]
])
```

Lets remove the `country` key:

```swift
object["two"].dictionaryObject?.removeValue(forKey: "country")
```

If you `print(object)`, you'll see that the `country` key no longer exists.

```json
{
  "one" : {
    "color" : "blue"
  },
  "two" : {
    "city" : "tokyo",
    "foods" : {
      "breakfast" : "tea",
      "lunch" : "sushi"
    }
  }
}
```

This also works for nested dictionaries:

```swift
object["two"]["foods"].dictionaryObject?.removeValue(forKey: "breakfast")
```

```json
{
  "one" : {
    "color" : "blue"
  },
  "two" : {
    "city" : "tokyo",
    "foods" : {
      "lunch" : "sushi"
    }
  }
}
```