# How to remove an item from JSON array in Swift (using SwiftyJSON)

Tags: ios, json, swift

Pretty simple and straightforward question.

I have a jsonArray, and i want to delete an item by index. How do I do that?

I tried using the solution from here:
https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON/issues/439

Like this:

```
jsonArray[row]["Likers"].array!.dictionaryObject?.removeValueForKey(index)
```

But I got this error:

```
value of type json has no member dictionaryObject
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I found the answer to remove an element in JSON (array type) created by SwiftyJSON:

```
dataObj.arrayObject?.removeAtIndex(m)
```

By the way, to remove an element when JSON returned by SwiftyJSON in a dictionary type:

```
jsonObj.dictionaryObject?.removeValueForKey(keyValue)
```

I'm getting this answer form [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34836400/how-to-remove-a-swiftyjson-element)

Answer (score 1):

you just use

```
yourJsonArry.removeAtIndex(2)
```

Hear you just pass the index that you want to remove items